# Default XAML page and New XAML page in Xamarin Forms is not identical

Tags: xaml, xamarin.forms

I am new to `Xamarin` development. I created new `Xamarin XAML App(Xamarin.Forms Portable)`. In Portable Project there where `MainPage.Xaml` by default. To create `MVVM` Model I created three new Folders- `Views, ViewModels,  and Models`. Now I added new `MainPage.Xaml` in Views folder and was going to delete the default `MainPage.Xaml` page. But here I see some difference in both pages. The default `MainPage.Xaml` have  `xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Test"`  but the new `MainPage.Xaml` does not. Again the new `MainPage.Xaml` have `<Label Text="{Binding MainText}" VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions="Center" />` but the default one does not. The screenshots are:
[image: New MainPage.Xaml in Views folder]

[image: Default MainPage.Xaml]

What does these MarkUp mean.Why there is a difference. Does something needs to be changed. Can I delete the default MainPage.Xaml or should i copy it in Views.Does I need to copy the Markup from the default Page to the new one. If so why? 
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Awesome that you have decided to start with Xamarin and Xamarin.Forms!

While I understand you might be having these questions, this is some very basic XAML knowledge. The short answer is: you don't need to worry about it.

The long answer:

The reason that there is a difference in these pages is simply because it's just a template and whoever at Xamarin created the template for the project can be a different person than who created the template for a new XAML page. So they solved it different ways. Or maybe he had a good/bad day, who knows.

The `Label` in the first page is simply there to show you how to get started and so you won't start with an empty screen.

The extra namespace `xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Test"` is actually redundant in this new page but is already there so you can use the classes in your project.

It is actually the equivalent of the `using` list at the top of your classes. So whenever you need something from a different namespace you have to declare it there. So if you create a folder 'Controls' you can add a attribute `xmlns:controls="clr-namespace:Test.Controls"`.

Note how I changed `local` to `controls`, this is the prefix you will use to define your instance. Also I have added the right namespace `Test.Controls`. Now if you want te show something on screen, in your XAML from the controls namespace, go like this:

```
<ContentPage xmlns:controls="clr-namespace:Test.Controls" x:Class="Test.MainPage">
  <!-- some stuff here -->
  <controls:ReusableControlHere />
</ContentPage>
```

Where `ReusableControl` can be your own version of a `Label`, `Button` or virtually anything.

Comment: Well explained! But `Label Text={Binding MainText}`. Can you tell what is MainText.

Comment: MainText should be a property of type string in your DataContext (your ViewModel)

Answer (score 3):

Both pages are identical, and will display in the same way.

On the second, there's an additional Xml namespace declaration:

```xml
xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Test"
```

It's only a declaration. You could remove it, or add it to the other page without effect. It's purpose is to be able to reference custom views declared in the current assembly and in the namespace (c# namespace, this time) `Test`, like this:

```xml
<ContentPage
    ...
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Test"
    x:Class="Test.MainPage">
  <local:MyAwesomeView />
</ContentPage>
```